401. Message: Must authenticate to access this API on GitHub Enterprise
What happened?
GItHub Octokit throws 401 error with GitHub App. Here is the code looks like
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import fs from 'fs'
import http from 'http'
import { Octokit, App } from 'octokit'
import { createNodeMiddleware } from '@octokit/webhooks'
import { createAppAuth } from "@octokit/auth-app";

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config()

// Set configured values
const { APP_ID, ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME, GITHUB_TOKEN, PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, WEBHOOK_SECRET, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env

const PRIVATE_KEY = fs.readFileSync(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, 'utf8')

// Create an authenticated Octokit client authenticated as a GitHub App
const app = new App({
  appId: APP_ID,
  privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
  webhooks: {
    secret: WEBHOOK_SECRET
  },
  ...(ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME && {
    Octokit: Octokit.defaults({
      auth: GITHUB_TOKEN,
      baseUrl: `https://${ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME}/api/v3`
    })
  })
})

app.webhooks.on('pull_request.opened', async ({ octokit, payload }) => {
  try {
    await octokit.rest.pulls.createReviewComment({
      owner: payload.repository.owner.login,
      repo: payload.repository.name,
      issue_number: payload.pull_request.number,
      body: "Add new code review comment"
    })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(`Error! Status 3: ${error.response.status}. Message: ${error.response.data.message}`)
    } else {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  try {
    const response = await octokit.rest.pulls.listFiles({
      owner: payload.repository.owner.login,
      repo: payload.repository.name,
      issue_number: payload.pull_request.number
    })
    console.log('Response: ', JSON.stringify(response))
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(`Error! Status 4: ${error.response.status}. Message: ${error.response.data.message}`)
    } else {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  try {
    await octokit.rest.pulls.requestReviewers({
      owner: payload.repository.owner.login,
      repo: payload.repository.name,
      issue_number: payload.pull_request.number,
      reviewers: ["user1"]
    })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(`Error! Status 5: ${error.response.status}. Message: ${error.response.data.message}`)
    } else {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
})

app.webhooks.onError((error) => {
  if (error.name === 'AggregateError') {
    console.log(`Error processing request: ${error.event}`)
  } else {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

// Launch a web server to listen for GitHub webhooks
const port = process.env.PORT || 3004
const path = '/api/webhook'
const localWebhookUrl = `http://localhost:${port}${path}`

// See https://github.com/octokit/webhooks.js/#createnodemiddleware for all options
const middleware = createNodeMiddleware(app.webhooks, { path })

http.createServer(middleware).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening for events at: ${localWebhookUrl}`)
  console.log('Press Ctrl + C to quit.')
})

Note -
All the values for APP_ID, ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME, GITHUB_TOKEN, PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, WEBHOOK_SECRET seems to be correct and verified.
Versions
Node v18, Octokit v4.0.2
Relevant log output
Error! Status 3: 401. Message: Must authenticate to access this API.
Error! Status 4: 401. Message: Must authenticate to access this API.
Error! Status 5: 401. Message: Must authenticate to access this API.

Without try catch:

AggregateError: 
    HttpError: Unauthorized. "POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/comments" failed most likely due to lack of authentication. Reason: "installation" key missing in webhook event payload
        at file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/octokit/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-bundle/index.js:106:21
        at async requestWithGraphqlErrorHandling (file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/octokit/node_modules/@octokit/plugin-retry/dist-bundle/index.js:36:20)
        at async Job.doExecute (/Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/bottleneck/light.js:405:18)
    at file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/@octokit/webhooks/dist-bundle/index.js:416:19
    at async middleware (file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/@octokit/webhooks/dist-bundle/index.js:604:5) {
  event: {
    id: '6fdae3a0-3d0d-11ef-833a-9857aeba7dcd',
    name: 'pull_request',
    payload: {
      action: 'opened',
      number: 62,
      pull_request: [Object],
      repository: [Object],
      enterprise: [Object],
      sender: [Object]
    }
  },
  errors: [
    RequestError [HttpError]: Unauthorized. "POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/comments" failed most likely due to lack of authentication. Reason: "installation" key missing in webhook event payload
        at file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/octokit/node_modules/@octokit/request/dist-bundle/index.js:106:21
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async requestWithGraphqlErrorHandling (file:///Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/octokit/node_modules/@octokit/plugin-retry/dist-bundle/index.js:36:20)
        at async Job.doExecute (/Users/user1/Documents/project/mytestapp/node_modules/bottleneck/light.js:405:18) {
      status: 401,
      request: [Object],
      response: [Object],
      event: [Object]
    }
  ]
}



Can anyone please help with the issue?

You can not create a pull request comment in a repo as a GitHub app. You have to make it as a GitHub app installation by presenting an installation id token. This token needs to be obtained every time you make a request or a group of requests. It is a short-lived token.
See here for details
You would need something like
const { App } = require("@octokit/app");
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");

// Create an authenticated Octokit client authenticated as a GitHub App installation
const app = new App({
  appId: APP_ID,
  privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
  webhooks: {
    secret: WEBHOOK_SECRET
  }
});

async function createInstallationClient(installationId) {
  // Get the installation access token
  const installationAccessToken = await app.getInstallationAccessToken({
    installationId: installationId
  });

  // Create an Octokit client authenticated as the installation
  const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: installationAccessToken,
    ...(ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME && {
      baseUrl: `https://${ENTERPRISE_HOSTNAME}/api/v3`
    })
  });

  return octokit;
}

// Example usage
const installationId = YOUR_INSTALLATION_ID; // Replace with your installation ID
createInstallationClient(installationId).then(octokit => {
  // Use the authenticated octokit client
 
});

